# Data not storing in database through user

Tags: python, django

I want to store Username in database using raw data I have some this But I am getting error. Please help me with this.

```
#models.py

class signup(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.username

#views.py

def sign(request):
    u = username.request.POST['username'])
    u.save()
    return render(request,'bookstore/signup.html',{'username':u})
```

and my error is :

> SyntaxError at /sign/invalid syntax (views.py, line 31)

Comment: You've got a single closing paren after `POST['username']` without any opening bracket before it; I'd guess that is your syntax error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you need to import the `signup` model:

```
#views.py
from models import signup

def sign(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    user = signup.objects.create(username=username)
    return render(request,'bookstore/signup.html',{'username': username})
```